# OO design filter shoes

Tags: function

I'm not quite familiar with OO design implementation. There's a OO design requirement. Suppose we have a set of shoes with shoe as an object. I need to create a function to return a set of shoes after user input some filter condition, like size, color, price range etc. It's possible that the filter condition could be expanded in the future. How can I create a good function with least code modification in the future?

Comment: Well where are you storing the set of shoes? As a static set?

Comment: @GermaineJason Return an arraylist of shoe is enough, like ArrayList<Shoe>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters often implemented using the [Decorator](http://www.gofpatterns.com/structural-design-patterns/structural-patterns/decorator-pattern.php) Pattern. For your shoes Problem the solution could be something like

```
/**
  * Empty default filter returns the original list.
  * Maybe this should be an Interface.
  */
public class ShoeFilter {


    List<Shoe> filter (List<Shoe> shoeList) {
       // default ist to do nothing.
       return shoeList; 
    }
}


public class SizeFilter extends ShoeFilter {
    private final ShoeFilter filter; // this can be also part of 
    private final int minSize; 
    private final int maxSize;

    public SizeFilter (ShoeFilter filter, int minSize, int maxSize) {
         this.filter = filter;
         this.minSize = minSize;
         this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public List<Shoe> filter (List<Shoe> list) { 
      List<Shoe> filteredList = filter.filter(list); // apply original filter

      // filter by size
    }
}


public class ColorFilter extends ShoeFilter {
    private final ShoeFilter filter;
    private final Color color; 

    public ColorFilter (ShoeFilter filter, Color color) {
         this.filter = filter;
         this.color = color;
    }

    public List<Shoe> filter(List<Shoe> list) {
       List<Shoe> filteredList = filter.filter(list); // apply original filter

       // filter by color
    }
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Shoe> shoes = ...;
    ShoeFilter emptyFilter = new ShoeFilter(); // can be a singleton

    ShoeFilter filter = new SizeFilter(new ColorFilter(emptyFilter, Color.Black), 39, 41);

    List<Shoe> filteredList = filter(shoes);


 }
```

To create the filter chain you can use a [Builder](http://www.gofpatterns.com/creational-design-patterns/creational-patterns/builder-pattern.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's pretty clear to me. So everytime if I need to create a new filter to get the shoes set, I just need to create a new filter class to implement the basic filter class.